# Discrete Mathematics (Determine whether R is true or false)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given the following collection of true statements, determine whether R is true or false.

(a) P ∨S

(b) (Q∧T) →∼R

(c) R →∼S

(d) ∼Q →∼P

(e) ∼S ∧T

I'm a bit confused with how to solve this kind of problem. I assume I create a truth table, however, how do I know the values for the S and T columns? I've seen P Q R truth tables, but nothing with S and T. Can somebody please show me how to determine if a and b are true/false, then I should be able to understand the rest.

So for a P Q R truth table:

```
P will be: T, T, T, T, F, F, F, F

Q will be: T, T, F, F, T, T, F, F

R will be: T, F, T, F, T, F, T, F
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: count in binary from 0 to 31.

Comment: @barrycarter Can you please elaborate a bit? Why 31? I know that 31 is 11111 in binary so I assume the answer is true? If so, I'd like to know a way to show some work as this type of problem will be on my exam. Thank you

Comment: OK, 11111 would be the case where P, Q, R, S, T are all true. 10011 (for example) would be the case where P is true, Q and R are false, and S and T are true. Does that make sense?

Comment: @barrycarter I get that... but I do not understand how to put in additional columns to a truth table for other variables (like S and T). I can only find examples with P Q R and sometimes S. Videos show to do 8 rows (P has 4 trues, 4 falses), (Q iterates with 2 trues and 2 falses), (R iterates with 1 true and 1 false). So is there some kind of special rule for S and T to memorize their columns?

Comment: Write down the binary numbers 0 to 31 one per row. Then write down five column headers for P, Q, R, S, T. Then, if there's a 0 in the first position, put down F for P. A 1 in the first position, but down T for P. Similarly, the second position represents the value of Q. And so on.